# Want to secure my app with combination of TouchID & email

Tags: ios, objective-c, mdm, touch-id

One of my app has log-in feature with email & password and it's working fine as expected.

Now, what my client wants here `email + TouchID` **(without password)** need to login into the app.

so my first question is can I do that with both combinations of `TouchID` & `email` login?

I have used Touch id for a simple unlock of my app but never use an email with `touchid` any idea how can I do that?

I have search and lot many apps are doing the same but how?

from one blog I found that with the help of `MDM` I can configure this but I haven't used `MDM` (Mobile device management) so not sure about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to link the touch id connection with the mail (like the touch id was the password) and not have to log with (mail+password) + touch id ? Need to be sure

Comment: yes touchId is my password

Comment: It's not possible that touch ID is only return success state that yes or no. So you can't bind it with email. @CodeChanger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `kSecAccessControlTouchIDCurrentSet` to store email into keychain at the time of registration. with this,  the item you will be storing into keychain will be combination of `Current TouchID + Email`.

At the time of login, You can retrieve Email from Keychain using touchId and and compare it with entered email.

To Store email into keychain, use following code : (works on iOS 9 and above-- Will not work on iOS 8)

```
-(void)saveToKeyChain:(NSString*)email{
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;

    SecAccessControlRef scaObject = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly, kSecAccessControlTouchIDCurrentSet,         &error);

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 (__bridge id)kSecClass:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                 (__bridge id)kSecAttrService  :@"ToucIdWithEmailExample",
                                  (__bridge id)kSecValueData    :[email dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                                  (__bridge id)kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI  :@YES,

                                  (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessControl  : (__bridge_transfer  id)scaObject
                                 };

    OSStatus initialWriteStatus =  SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes, nil);

}

kSecAccessControlTouchIDCurrentSet in above will take store Email with current authenticated touch.
```

To retrive keychain data, you can use following:

```
-(void)retriveKeyChainData{

    NSDictionary *queryAttributes = @{
                                 (__bridge id)kSecClass:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                 (__bridge id)kSecAttrService  :@"ToucIdWithEmailExample",
                                 (__bridge id)kSecReturnData    : @YES,

                                 (__bridge id)kSecUseOperationPrompt  : @"Authenticate"
                                 }.mutableCopy;

    CFTypeRef dataTypeRef = NULL;
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryAttributes, &dataTypeRef);

    if(status == errSecSuccess)
    {
        NSData *data = (__bridge NSData*)(dataTypeRef);
    }



}
```

This function will retrieve Email id which you stored at the time of registration. You can compare it with entered email and Validate.

you can go through this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password) - if you want to understand it in detail.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Above thing will help me if registration go through mobile app but in my case there is no registration from mobile app so is there any other way to store email with `touchId` ?

Comment: If registration is not from mobile, Then How to identify if emailed entered In mobile is Linked with user who has authenticated with touch?  if registration is done from web-there must be password , So  when user comes to app for the first time, ask to enter email and password and validate it on server, if its validated, save email into keychain with Touched.

Comment: Ok Nice idea let me try that in my app, Thanks for your comment and guided me on right path.

Answer (score 2):

As i said in comment, i think this not possible cause touch ID will always return to you `true` or `false`.

But you can use `KeyChainTouchID` to store and protect your mail value. So, your user have to put his mail, use touch id to verify that the mail stored in the keychain is the same.

Doc : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

On your device you can store multiple fingerprint samples. However from the OS you do not get a reply which finger is okay. Just if the entered finger is okay or not.

So it is not possible to identify users (or email addresses) based on the entered finger.

TouchID is an access control mechanism, not an identification mechanism.